# htaccess RewriteRule not firing

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My directory structure is

```
domain.com/project1
domain.com/project1/,htaccess
domain.com/project1/api.php
```

The .htaccess is

```
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteRule /([^\.]+)/([^\.]+).(xml|json) /api.php?version=$1&url=$2&type=$3
```

So going to domain.com/project1/v1/users.json should direct me to domain.com/project1/api.php?version=v1&url=users&type=json but I get a 404 saying

```
The requested URL /project1/v1/users.json was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

Comment: What is the document root?

Comment: Try removing `/` before `/api.php?...`

Comment: Removing the / did not fix it. What do you mean the document root?

Comment: Does your other .htaccess code work?

Answer (score 0):

This rule should work from `/project1/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /project1/

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)\.(xml|json)$ api.php?version=$1&url=$2&type=$3 [L,QSA]
```

- Leading slash isn't matched in .htaccess
- You must use anchors `^` and `$` to get precise matching
- Escape the DOT in regex
- Though not required but it is good to use `QSA` (query string append) flag.